# Is there a significant performance cost to using lots of nested partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partials

I have a page that uses a lot of nested partials to display content according to user type and product status across a range of categories. Is it a good idea to manage this using nested partials and conditional status? I wonder if there is a performance hit to all of this?

For example - product.html.erb:

```
<% if product.status == "available" %>
  <%= render available_product %>
<% else %>
  <%= render manage_supplier %>
<% end %>
```

And available_product.html.erb:

```
<% if @user.role == owner %>
  <%= render product_headline_form %>
<% else %>
  <%= render product_headline_show %>
<% end %>
<%= render some_nice_stuff_from_supplier %>
```

... and on.

I'm keeping my partials pretty atomised 'cos I figure it will give me more flexibility when I come to add ajax in places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that depends on

- the ruby version
- the rails version
- your partials

in other words: *you have to measure*

in general: partials tend to be much slower than ie helpers because rails has to do much more work to setup the rendering context for a partial than it has to do if there are none.

is it relevant? depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought there might be a cost. Do you have a link for further info of this? I've had a search around but can't find much.

Comment: it's simple, add a benchmark call around your partial invocation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html